# Edit a html getting from backend and render it in a react website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
let htmlFromBackend = `Some backend HTML in table format`

return (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlFromBackend}}></div>
)
```

I want to add some buttons(I want to add a button in every `<tr></tr>`) and elements in the html getting from backend. How it can be acheived?

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest solution, you can prepend the HTML directly. For example:

```
return (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `<button onclick="alert('Nice!')">Alert</button>${htmlFromBackend}`}}></div>
)
```

To prepend buttons on multiple elements of the HTML, you can either use RegExp or parse it first. I'll show you an example that parses the HTML first and edit it.

```
function preprocessHTML(html){
    const element=document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML=html;

    // do any operations you like, for example:
    for(const child of element.children){
        const btn=document.createElement('button');
        btn.innerText='Click Me!';
        child.prepend(btn);    
    }

    return element.innerHTML;
}

return (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: preprocessHTML(htmlFromBackend)}}></div>
)
```

---

If you want to prepend with React, you can use [`ReactDOM.createPortal`](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to render any JSX element to any HTMLDom.

Comment: This will add only one button. I want to add button in every <tr></tr> it have.